# I can't figure out why this contact form isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm stumped on why this form isn't working. I get the successful message, but nothing's being sent into my inbox, and I've checked my spam too. Even after waiting for a couple of minutes, still nothing shows up. I'm not really familiar with ajax or php, so I might have done something wrong with that part.

I'm using two plugins, http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js and http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js.

html ("corner" divs are merely for styling purposes)

```
       <form action="contact-form.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="contact">

            <div class="corner"></div>
            <input type="text" required name="name" placeholder="Name" class="name">

            <div class="corner"></div>
            <input type="email" required name="email" placeholder="Email" class="email">

            <div class="corner"></div>
            <div id="contact-check">You sure 'bout that?</div>
            <input type="text" required name="check" placeholder="Quick! What's 2 + 2 ?" class="check">

            <div class="corner"></div>
            <textarea name="message" rows="25" cols="50" placeholder="Drop me a line!"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="send" />
        </form>
```

jquery (using ajax)

```
var contactForm = $('form#contact')
    inputCheck = $('input.check')
    contactCheck = $('div#contact-check');

// Check if answered math question correctly
inputCheck.keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 4){
        contactCheck.fadeOut();
    } else {
        contactCheck.fadeIn();
    }
});

// Validate input from contact form
$('form#contact').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
      clearForm: true,
      success: function(){
        // if it's good, do this
        contactCheck.fadeOut();
        alert("Thanks, I'll get back to you soon!");
      }
    });
    return false;
  },
  invalidHandler: function(form) {
    // if it's bad, do this
    alert('Oops, something went wrong.');
  }
});
```

Finally php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = filter_var( $_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: MessageForAnita'; 
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$check = $_POST['check'];

$body = " From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";


if ($_POST['submit'] && $check == '4') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo 'Your message was sent!';
    } else { 
        echo 'Something went wrong, go back and try again!'; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: check the mail server log

Comment: Most SMTP servers require a valid "from" address. "FROM: MessageForAnita" is not a valid address. Fix it to something like "From: MessageForAnita <website@example.com>". But aside from that, you really should check your serverlogs for any errors.

Comment: PHP **LIES** about the message being sent. mail() returning true means ONLY that the email was successfully handed off to your mail server. After that, it can STILL get trashed/lost/rejected/blahb/blah blah blah.

Comment: @MarcB it's not really that it lies, but more that due to the nature of the protocol (SMTP), it can only tell you if the message was successfully passed to a mail transfer agent.

Comment: @T0xicCode: far too many people take a `true` return from mail() to mean that the recipient received/read the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the php to

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
$subject = 'You have a message sent from your site';

$check = $_POST['check'];

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

and I'm fortunately receiving notification of new mail. However $name, $email, and $message have no values so I only get an email of "From: E-Mail: Message:" On to troubleshooting this next problem. Thanks for all the comments though. Also still need make this form more secure.

UPDATE:
I finally figured it out. A few days ago I changed my .htaccess file and I forgot to take out the .php extension when linking to the contact form. How incredibly simple is that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the headers that you're send and make sure they are formatted properly.

this isn't tested, but gives you an idea of what you should be doing:

```
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$message    = $_POST['message'];
$email      = filter_var( $_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );

$to         = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
$subject    = 'Hello MessageForAnita';
$body       = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$body       = wordwrap($body, 70, "\r\n");

$headers    = "From: $email" . "\r\n"; 

if ($_POST['submit'] && $check == '4') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
        echo 'Your message was sent!';
    } else { 
        echo 'Something went wrong, go back and try again!'; 
    } 
}
```

[PHP mail function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)